# Aether: How to get non-transitive dependencies of an artifact?

Tags: dependencies, maven-3, aether

There are plenty of examples floating around the web for calculating an artifact's [transitive dependencies using Aether](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Resolving_Dependencies). That being said, how do I get an artifact's **immediate** dependencies (one level deep)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I found GetDirectDependencies.java in "Aether Demo Snipplets" taken from http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2010, 2012 Sonatype, Inc.
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 *
 * Contributors:
 *    Sonatype, Inc. - initial API and implementation
 *******************************************************************************/
package org.eclipse.aether.examples;

import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem;
import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession;
import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.Artifact;
import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact;
import org.eclipse.aether.examples.util.Booter;
import org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency;
import org.eclipse.aether.repository.RemoteRepository;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorRequest;
import org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorResult;

/**
 * Determines the direct dependencies of an artifact as declared in its artifact descriptor (POM).
 */
public class GetDirectDependencies
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------------" );
        System.out.println( GetDirectDependencies.class.getSimpleName() );

        RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

        RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( system );

        Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:1.13" );

        RemoteRepository repo = Booter.newCentralRepository();

        ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
        descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
        descriptorRequest.addRepository( repo );

        ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );

        for ( Dependency dependency : descriptorResult.getDependencies() )
        {
            System.out.println( dependency );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: anyway to get the 'resolved' dependencies from these? Does this download the jars in your local repo?